# Not able to timeout using python eventlet library (eventlet.timeout.Timeout)

Tags: python, python-3.x, timeout, try-catch, eventlet

I am looping over a list and performing some action on each member of the list.
If a member takes too much time (1 sec in this case), I intend to pass it. However the block inside the `try` statement is always being processed and is **never timing out**. I don't understand why.

```
    from eventlet import *        

    for rule in data:

        #Timeout block
        t=Timeout(1)
        try:
            f = expr2bdd(expr(rule))
            solutions = satisfy_all(f, count=True)
            each_rule["solution"]=solutions
        except:
            pass
        finally:
            t.cancel()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Eventlet is a concurrent networking library...

It's not clear what `expr2bdd` and `satisfy_all` functions do, but most likely they only do some CPU calculations and no disk/network IO. In this case there is no point where Eventlet gets a chance to run and fire timeout exception.

If you have control over `expr2bdd` and `satisfy_all` functions and there are any kind of loops, place `eventlet.sleep(0)` at each iteration. That's Eventlet idiom for "yield control to other coroutines", that's where timeout will be fired.

If you don't have control over said functions, second best option is to run them in a separate process which you can forcefully kill. On POSIX compatible OS (e.g. Linux, *BSD, OSX), you can use `os.fork` to run a piece of code in separate process. For maximum portability, use `subprocess.Popen([sys.executable,...])` or `multiprocessing.Process`. The latter gives higher level API, mainly around easier data exchange (serialization) at the cost of performance overhead, which may be negligible in your case. In any case, basic pattern is this: (in a thread or eventlet coroutine, you start a second process and then `.communicate()/join()` on it. Use `eventlet.Timeout` or `Thread.join()` with timeout. If timeout fires, use `p.terminate()` or `p.kill()` to stop current calculations.

Comment: They certainly don't do any disk/network IO. `expr2bdd` is a function from a library called [pyeda](http://pyeda.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) (used for boolean algebra processing),` satisfy_all` is my wrapper around the `satisfy_all/satisfy_one` function from the same library. I can look into the code for `expr2bdd` , but want to avoid it. Can you suggest something else so that I can bypass the `expr2bdd` function whenever it's taking long time to process. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: @Shivendra I've updated the answer with second option if you can't change those functions. Good luck!